# Having two servers run off two different ips but run on the same port

Tags: networking, ip

I have a dedicated server that I use for Minecraft servers. On these servers, I have given them both their own IP address. Is it possible to have them both run on the same port?

Answer (score 1):

If the Minecraft servers can be configured to bind to a particular IP address, and each one is configured for a different IP (but not "any" IP), then yes each one can listen on the same port.  Doesn't matter if it's TCP or UDP.

Comment: I did that, but I guess I must have set up the ip's wrong in Debian